# Get data result from external function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a external function that gets data from a json file, and i want to use this function for my component to have question data for questions, how can i manage this to work?

Here is what i tried and it won't work :

THE COMPONENT :

### screens/QuizzQuestion.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native';
import { getQuestionData } from '../utils/utils'

export default class QuizzQuestion extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      info:null
    };
  }

loadData(){
    getQuestionData(2).then(data=>{
      this.setState({ info: data })
  });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }
```

THE EXTERNAL FUNCTION :

### /utils/utils.js

```js
import * as data from "../assets/questions/questions.json";

export function getQuestionData(n){
   return data.questions[n];
}
```

I have this error every single time :

TypeError: TypeError: (0, _utils.getQuestionData)(0).then is not a function. (In '(0, _utils.getQuestionData)(0).then(function (data) {
          _this2.setState({
            info: data
          });
        })', '(0, _utils.getQuestionData)(0).then' is undefined)
* screens\QuizzQuestion.js:20:28 in loadData
* screens\QuizzQuestion.js:26:4 in componentDidMount
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15036:10 in commitLifeCycles
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16636:8 in commitAllLifeCycles
- ... 18 more stack frames from framework internals

Comment: `getQuestionData` doesn't return a promise but your trying to use it like it does.

Comment: `loadData(){ this.setState({ info: getQuestionData(2) }); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export function getQuestionData(n){
  return data.questions[n];
}
```

This returns the question from your questions array in your data object. It *doesn't* return a promise. So when you try and use it like it returns a promise...

```
getQuestionData(2).then(data => {
  this.setState({ info: data })
});
```

...it will break and produce that error.

So simply grab the question and set the state like this:

```
const question = getQuestionData(2);
this.setState({ info: question });
```

Alternatively - *note there's no reason to do this* - make the function [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```js
const data = { questions: ['Question1', 'Question2', 'Question3'] };

async function getQuestionData(n){
  return data.questions[n];
}

getQuestionData(2).then(q => console.log(q));
```

Answer (score 0):

`getQuestionData` is synchronous and not a promise. Therefore, you simply need to assign the returned value from `getQuestionData` into the desired state property.

```
loadData(){
  const data = getQuestionData(2);
  this.setState({ info: data });
}
```